# Building a syntax checker

Tags: syntax, ide, syntax-error, validation

I am building a app like a compiler with my own script language. The user will enter the code and the output will be another app.
So I need tell to user if some line is wrong and why it is.

But I don't know how to start.

I thought this:
All lines will start with a keyword, except for those who start with an variable. So different that are wrong.
So, I can calculate the next valid entries and check them.

Also, I thought that I can check each line, but it's complex because I can have this

```
var varName { /* ... */ };
```

Or

```
var varName {
/* ... */
};
```

Or Even

```
var varName
{
/* ... */
};
```

So why not remove the break-lines and check? Because I will lose the line number, which in this case is the most important. 
Maybe I'm going to create a map between the code with and without break-line.

But first I want to hear you, if you already has this experience or you have any idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are formal languages to describe syntax and semantics of the language and there are tools that will generate parsers out of these descriptions. I suggest reading on flex and bison for starters.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be fairly complicated to write your own language. But totally doable.

To able to recognize if a line is wrong, in the syntactical sense, you'd need to build a parser.
The parser checks the context-free grammar for a correct derivation of a structure from its tokens.

First you need to tokenize the file, then reconstruct it into a parse tree (to check syntax).

I took a class in this, CS 241. There's a very nice set of course notes which this is all explained in detail. 
https://github.com/christhomson/lecture-notes/blob/master/cs241.pdf

Comment: Thank you @sunapi386, will be usefull

Answer (score 1):

You should check tools like: `lex`, `bison` and `yacc`.

`lex` is lexical analyser generator. It generates a code, which could be used for breaking the script to tokens (like numbers, keywords and so on...).

`bison` and `yacc` are both parser generators. Both can be used for generating code for parsing your language (combining tokens to statements).

Just google tutorials for those tools.

Comment: I was just reading about the Irony project http://irony.codeplex.com/. I don't read that much to be sure, but I think I can use it.